# How can you stop Google Analytics 4 from automatically sending an outbound link click event?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics-4

We have a site that is sending events directly to GA4 (not Google Tag Manager) and we are using a CDN to host some PDFs. This CDN uses GUIDs instead of file paths/file names, so there is no file extension, which means that the automatic detection Google has for tracking file downloads does not detect it, and instead triggers a click event on an outbound link. I am trying to disable this behavior for these specific links, and instead send a file_download event. I have constructed that event, and it is firing fine, but the click event is still firing no matter what. Is there a way to stop this behavior for some links, but not all that does not require the use of Tag Manager?

I have tried preventing default behavior, but the event still fires. I have not come across any other documentation for how to do this or something like this with the other automatically detected events. The only advice I have seen is to disable it entirely, which I don't want to do.

Comment: I'm not sure if this solution works. call it when click event firing: `event.stopPropagation()`

Comment: My understanding of this, is that it will halt all event handlers on the rest of the page, which I would like to avoid if possible.

Comment: I think if you share part of your code that has problem the people can help you better. [more info](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)